Identify set that multicolored bags without a box came from

I have 8 bags that simply have an "05 in a triangle with PP under it" and "2021 The Lego Group" on them. Looking to find what set they are from so we can download the instructions.

A lot of the smallest sets came in bags without boxes. I think the Lego pieces in those bags must come from one of the "classic" sets, that is, the sets mainly consisting of plain Lego bricks and having no instructions for a specific model. These are the creative sets which encourage building whatever you want, rather than a prescribed model.

The contents of the bags are consistent with set 11014 "bricks and wheels":

In particular:

Blue 4 x 6 plate
Bright pink 2 x 3 plate
Light Bluish Gray Wheel 18mm D. x 14mm with Pin Hole, Fake Bolts and Shallow Spokes
White round 1x1 tile with squinting eye pattern

However, the two top bags do not match the contents of that set - I believe they belong to set 11013 "creative transparent bricks" instead, due to:

2 of 2x2 flower, solid stud in yellow
2x2x2 container box in white
2x1 plate with 3 teeth in white
2x1 brick without bottom tube in trans-bright green



Once you have the set number, it's easy to search for instructions in the Customer Service section of the LEGO website.
